# rename multiple files with one variable

Tags: rename, mv

I am trying to rename one file with one variable.

Example: `2014.001.**.**.**.D890.E.m` to `IP.PMST..BHE.D.2014.001`.

#### My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/pintolcv/Downloads

for jd in {001..366}
do

mv 2014.$jd.*.*.D890.E.m IP.PMST..BHE.D.2014.$jd 

done
```

But I always see this error:

```
mv: cannot stat `2014.001.*.*.D890.E.m': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `2014.002.*.*.D890.E.m': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `2014.003.*.*.D890.E.m': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `2014.004.*.*.D890.E.m': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `2014.005.*.*.D890.E.m': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `2014.006.*.*.D890.E.m': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `2014.007.*.*.D890.E.m': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `2014.008.*.*.D890.E.m': No such file or directory
..
..
.. and so on!
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: Please provide an example filename (without wildcards) so we can see what you are trying to match.

Comment: there are 3 level of * in the first line, and 2 * in the shell.

Comment: now I come to think of it  `mv 2014.$jd.*.D890.E.m IP.PMST..BHE.D.2014.$jd` (with one *) sould be enough.

Comment: Just quote it. If you have a file named `2014.001.**.**.**.D890.E.m` then you should put quotes around its name when attempting to rename it. Also, stop naming your files like that.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed script:

```
for file in /home/pintolcv/Downloads/2014*D890.E.m; do

filepath=${file%/*}
filebasename=${file##*/}

#echo "File equals: $file"
#echo "File path equals: $filepath"
#echo "File basename equals: $filebasename"

    if [[ -e "$file" ]]; then
        echo "File Found: $filebasename - ${filebasename:5:3}"
        mv "$file" "$filepath/IP.PMST.BHE..D.2014.${filebasename:5:3}"
    else
        echo "files do not exist"
    fi

done
```

Comment: Hi DevNull,                                        Thanks for your time to help me. Something missing: The output on terminal is:                               File Found: /home/pintolcv/Downloads/2014.046.00.00.00.D890.E.m - /pi
mv: cannot move `/home/pintolcv/Downloads/2014.046.00.00.00.D890.E.m' to `IP.PMST.BHE..D.2015./pi': No such file or directory
files do not exist
But the file that i want to rename is on /home/pintolcv/Downloads/2014.046.00.00.00.D890.E.m                                        Thanks,                                                 LP

Comment: Sorry DevNull, It's not my personal convention. I never would choose this parameters. pintolcv@lapsis122:~/Downloads$ ls -l 2014.046.00.00.00.D890.E.m 
-rw-r--r-- 1 pintolcv pintolcv 7548928 Feb 23 11:28 2014.046.00.00.00.D890.E.m
It's a file, not a directory. Yes two dots. It's not a typo error. It was like my first question. Thank you in advance for your patience. LP

Comment: @user3683346 I am sorry. When I wrote that script it was late and I completely overlooked important things like paths during the moves since I tested in local directories. Try the above script. That should work. I also included the echos (although they are commented out) for debugging if anything still fails.